# Impress.js set Slide Width to 100%

Tags: jquery, css, impress.js

I was just trying out [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/) plugin. i tried setting the width of slides to 100% but it seems to be not taking the width in percentage....

Any fix for this will be very helpful.